# How to set by api to use HTTPS (error net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: php, apache, ssl, server, httpd.conf

I have setup my frontend an my backend with apache and both worked with http. The front end (react) is setup on port 80 with a virtual host (see below) and the api (php) is using port 8080 with a virtual host too. The folder structure is having my backend and front end in the same root projet folder:

```
-folder
    -frontend
        -build folder
    -rest-api-authentification
        -api folder
```

I setup my domain xxxx.ca with cerbot and my frontend is working on https://xxxx.ca. But now it's my api that I can't seems to make work. I can call the api alone with postman at http://xxxx.ca/api/test.php and it works. Same when using curl http://xxxx.ca/api/test.php on the server.

What is the config that is missing to use my api in https (the way is needs to be called is https://xxxx.ca/api/test.php).

Do I need another certificate for my api event if it's on the same domain but using the port 8080? I Tried to use a proxy to redirect calls from the /api without success.

Thanks!

Here are the virtual hosts that i have setup

domain@react.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/mnt/example/frontend/build"
        ServerName xxxx.ca
        ServerAlias www.xxxx.ca

        <Directory "/mnt/example/frontend/build">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.ca/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.ca/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

domain@react-le-ssl.conf (auto-generated)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/mnt/example/frontend/build"
        ServerName xxxx.ca
        ServerAlias www.xxxx.ca

        <Directory "/mnt/example/frontend/build">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        #I added this section as a test
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/api
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/api

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.ca/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.ca/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

domain@api.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        DocumentRoot "/mnt/example/rest-api-authentication"
        ServerName xxxx.ca
        ServerAlias www.xxxx.ca       

        <Directory "/mnt/example/rest-api-authentication">
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your `<VirtualHost *:8080>` does not contain _any_ SSL configuration at all.

Comment: You are right it's now working thanks!